Modified Special Geometry of SUSY Moduli Space
It is known that the Coulomb branches of 5d $\mathcal{N}=1$ and 4d $\mathcal{N}=2$
SUSY (both have eight supercharges) satisfy special geometry. This means that there exists a holomorphic prepotential $\mathcal{F}$ such that the Coulomb branch is given by the hypersurface
$$\mathcal{CB}=\{T^I,I=0,...,n_V\vert\mathcal{F}[T]=1\},$$
where $n_V$ denotes the number of vector multiplets.
It is also known that higher-derivative corrections to supergravities change this special geometry constraint, see e.g. this post.
$\textbf{Question:}$ How can this new, modified constraint be interpreted? Is the Coulomb branch still given by the hypersurface $\mathcal{F}[T]=1$ or by the new constraint $\mathcal{F}[T]=1+\mathcal{G}[T]$? If the latter is true, does this mean that higher-derivative corrections break special geometry and also the direct product structure of the SUSY moduli space?
$\textbf{Remark:}$ From geometric engineering (M-Theory on elliptically fibered CY$_3$), I would expect the former to be true. However, I am very unsure about this!
$\textbf{Edit:}$ Maybe I should be more explicit on why this correction concerns me. Consider M-Theory on a Calabi-Yau threefold $Y$. Then the Kähler moduli space is identified with the $\mathcal{N}=1$ Coulomb branch in five dimensions. The prepotential $\mathcal{F}$ is in this case simply the total volume $\mathcal{V}_Y$ of $Y$ which sits in a 5d hypermultiplet. Keeping $\mathcal{F}\equiv\mathcal{V}_Y=1$ fixed gives a constraint on the scalars of the vector multiplets (corresponding to the Kähler parameters of $Y$) and this constrained hypersurface is then the Coulomb branch. So far, so good.
What I find worrying is that with the inclusion of
$$S_{ARR}\sim\int_{\mathcal{M}_5}C_IA^I\wedge\mathrm{tr}R^2,$$
the condition $\mathcal{F}[T]=1$ is replaced by $\mathcal{F}[T]=1+\mathcal{G}[T]$ and it seems to me that now there is no clear distinction between Coulomb and Higgs branch possible anymore. This seems particularly strange as I always considered the direct product structure to be a very rigid condition coming from SUSY and seeing it broken due to a higher-derivative correction feels weird.

Maybe it's some kind of deformation that preserves the product structure? But I don't have a reference...

@MitchellPorter Thank you for your comment! I'm not sure. In geometric engineering (M-Theory on CY$_3$), the Kähler moduli space (= bottom-up Coulomb branch) is classically exact, i.e. $\mathcal{F}$ will remain to be the volume of the CY$_3$ no matter what. But since this volume is a hypermultiplet scalar, the modified constraint seems to mix this "hypermultiplet fixing" with certain quantities Coulomb branch quantities. To me this seems to breack the product structure.

I was encouraged to think in terms of deformation by the last paragraph of https://www.physicsoverflow.org/31539, which talks about quantum corrections affecting the metric of the moduli space, but not global properties. But I haven't checked whether your modified constraint is in any way comparable.
